# Run integration and unit tests using Gradle JVMTestSuite plugin

Tags: gradle, integration-testing, jvm-test-suite

I am trying to convert a maven project to gradle, and am struggling to get integration tests running. I am trying to use the recommended [JVMTestSuite plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html#jvm_test_suite_plugin), but the integration tests do not run correctly.

Using the example on the documentation, the current setup I have is this:

```
testing {
    suites {
        test {
            useJUnitJupiter()
        }

        integrationTest(JvmTestSuite) {
            testType.set(TestSuiteType.INTEGRATION_TEST)

            dependencies {
                implementation project()
            }

            targets {
                all {
                    testTask.configure {
                        shouldRunAfter(test)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
tasks.named('check') { 
    dependsOn(testing.suites.integrationTest)
}
```

When I run `./gradlew integrationTest`, the build succeeds but no tests are being executed. When I run `./gradlew test`, all the unit tests and integration tests run, but the integration tests fail as the Spring context is not set up correctly.

End result I would like is:

- `test` command runs only unit tests
- `integrationTest` sets up Spring context and executes tests
- Each set of tests is filtered by name (eg. filtering "*IT.java" rather than using separate folder structures)

Is someone able to help with this? The documentation does not seem to lead to a working example. Thank you :)

Comment: Is your integration test source code in the src/integrationTest folder right now? If not might be worth moving it there and getting it working first, and then you can look at adding filters for the tests using sources.java.include and sources.java.exclude

Comment: Thanks that was definitely a good point! I now have them running in the integrationTest folder but still not correctly. When using gradle integrationTest task, the Spring context does not start so all the tests fail. In Maven, Spring starts and the tests pass, so I assume it's not the test code. Any ideas of further configuration that's required? Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not a Spring user I'm afraid. Your current setup should have all the same Spring code on the classpath as your main application, ready to go... you need to find the way to get it started :)

Comment: Turns out the issue was a maven property referenced in the application.yaml file. Frustratingly, the gradle integration test task did not show the error when running, so it was difficult to trace. Thanks for the help :)